# remove null atributes from json with gson

Tags: java, javascript, json, gson

I want to remove attributes that have empty collections or null values using gson.

```
Aiperiodo periodo = periodoService();
//periodo comes from a service method with a lot of values
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(periodo);
```

I print json and I have this:

```
{"idPeriodo":121,"codigo":"2014II",
"activo":false,"tipoPeriodo":1,
"fechaInicioPreMatricula":"may 1, 2014",
"fechaFinPreMatricula":"jul 1, 2014",
"fechaInicioMatricula":"jul 15, 2014",
"fechaFinMatricula":"ago 3, 2014",
"fechaInicioClase":"ago 9, 2014",
"fechaFinClase":"dic 14, 2014",
"fechaActa":"ene 15, 2015",
"fechaUltModificacion":"May 28, 2014 12:28:26 PM",
"usuarioModificacion":1,"aiAvisos":[],
"aiAlumnoCarreraConvalidacionCursos":[],
"aiAlumnoMatriculas":[],"aiMallaCurriculars":[],
"aiAlumnoCarreraEstados":[],"aiAdmisionGrupos":[],
"aiMatriculaCronogramaCabeceras":[],
"aiAlumnoCarreraConvalidacions":[],
"aiHorarioHorases":[],"aiAsistencias":[],
"aiAlumnoPreMatriculas":[],
"aiAlumnoMatriculaCursoNotaDetalles":[],
"aiOfertaAcademicas":[],"aiTarifarios":[]}
```

For example for that json I don't want to have the collection aiAvisos, there is a way to delete this from the json.
I'm working with a lot of collections actually here I show one, I really need remove these from the json.

I need something like this:

```
{"idPeriodo":121,"codigo":"2014II",
"activo":false,"tipoPeriodo":1,
"fechaInicioPreMatricula":"may 1, 2014",
"fechaFinPreMatricula":"jul 1, 2014",
"fechaInicioMatricula":"jul 15, 2014",
"fechaFinMatricula":"ago 3, 2014",
"fechaInicioClase":"ago 9, 2014",
"fechaFinClase":"dic 14, 2014",
"fechaActa":"ene 15, 2015",
"fechaUltModificacion":"May 28, 2014 12:28:26 PM",
"usuarioModificacion":1}
```

I tried setting the collections to null, I check the documentation and there's no method there neither...

Please any suggestions.
Yeah I update the json I had posted some minutes ago.

Thanks a lot who read this!

Comment: Hi oshingc, what have you tried so far & what hasn't worked as you expected? Please elaborate with some example code & a specific problem.

Comment: It's not a valid JSON. Check it here [The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @Braj I update the json I was showing at the post, I'm working with a valid JSON actually. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Steps to follow:

- Convert the JSON String into `Map<String,Object>` using [Gson#fromJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- Iterate the map and remove the entry from the map which are `null` or empty `ArrayList`.
- Form the JSON String back from the final map using [Gson#toJson()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29).

**Note :** Use [GsonBuilder#setPrettyPrinting()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setPrettyPrinting%28%29) that configures Gson to output Json that fits in a page for pretty printing.

Find the sample code here [Remove empty collections from a JSON with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920740/remove-empty-collections-from-a-json-with-gson?answertab=votes#tab-top)