# Java Regex Replace Non-Greedy not work

Tags: java, json, regex, non-greedy

I want to delete all `"key":null` patterns from json string.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"a\":null,\"b\":1,\"c\":null,\"d\":5}";
System.out.println(jsonStr.replaceAll("\".*?\":null,", ""));
```

I expected

```
{"b":1,"d":5}
```

But result is

```
{"d":5}
```

Obviously, non greedy is not applied.

I tried with `Pattern`, `Matcher`. But it also results in same result.

```
Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\".*?\":null,");
Matcher matcher = replace.matcher(jsonStr);
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(""));
```

Comment: Replace `"\".*?\":null,"` with `"\"[^\"]*\":null,"` as `.` matches any char.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Better yet, use a JSON parser.  A bit more overhead, but as the JSON grows, this is probably a safer option.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You could help better if you found a good close reason. All these comments "use what you have never seen before" do not really help OPs.

Comment: Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039207/jsonobject-remove-empty-value-pairs) is better. Closed with the post with the regex issue explanation and that JSON related one.