# Converting an empty JSONArray to String

Tags: java, json

There's a feature in the UI to enter description text.

When a user enters an empty [] in the UI, that gets converted as an empty JSONArray and it throws an exception since the code expects a String however gets a JSONArray.

Input coming from UI:

`{&quot;original&quot;:{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;[rtsASDl&quot;},&quot;modified&quot;:{&quot;description&quot;:&quot;[]&quot;}}`

Raw data gets cleaned in this line. Result looks like:

String rawData = EncodeSpecialCharactersFilter.unclean(data);

`{"original":{"description":"[rtsASDl"},"modified":{"description":"[]"}}`

Upon converting this to JSONObject, the empty array [] gets converted to JSONArray.

JSONObject containerData = JSONObject.fromObject(rawData);

```
 key = "description"
 value = {JSONArray@26344}  size = 0

Is it possible to make it a String instead?
```

Comment: add more detail.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039207/jsonobject-remove-empty-value-pairs/31040819